# How to add Btree or hash index to a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables and two queries on those tables. I am using SQL workbench to query these tables. Can someone tell me the syntax of adding BTREE or HASH index to these tables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`CREATE INDEX` supports `USING BTREE` or `USING HASH` on the end.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Which one is the default type?

Comment: BTREE is the default.

Comment: also HASH indexes are only for in-memory tables (or NDB) but not myISAM or InnoDB